# Understanding rate of convergence and order of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand what is the difference between 'rate of convergence' and 'order of convergence'. Does anyone know an intuitive explanation of the difference between them?

For example, say I have the sequence defined by $(1 + 1/n^2)$, $n>=1$

So it looks like $2, 1\frac{1}{4}, 1 \frac{1}{9}, 1 \frac{1}{16},...$

And has a limit of $1$ as n approaches infinity. So what is the rate of convergence and order of convergence for this example?

And how does that sequence tie in with the convergence equation ([Wikipedia - Convergence speed for iterative methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence)) -

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_k - L|^q} = μ | μ > 0$$

Answer (score 16):

Following the relevant [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) article, note that the *rate of convergence* is the number $\mu\in (0,1)$ such that

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_k - L|} = \mu $$

provided such a $\mu$ exists and $\{x_k\}$ converges to L. If this holds, $\{x_k\}$ is said to converge linearly to L. Note that the *rate of convergence* only exists if $\{x_k\}$ *converges linearly* to L!

But what if the above limit exists and equals $0$? Then $\{x_k\}$ is said to converge *superlinearly*.

*Order of convergence* is an additional definition use to distinguish between sequences that converge *superlinearly*. Such a sequence $\{x_k\}$ has *order of convergence* q if

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_k - L|^q} = C\:,\textrm{ for }\:q>1$$

Given that $C$ is a positive constant, and $\{x_k\}$ converges to L. This is the equation you have included in your question. $q$ need not be an integer, as in the case of the secant method, where q is in fact the golden ratio $\approx 1.618$.

The best intuitive explanation that I can give is that *rate of convergence* and *order of convergence* are two numbers used to describe the speed of different kinds of convergence. A sequence has either a *rate of convergence* (if the convergence is linear) or an *order of convergence* (if the convergence is *superlinear*), and not both. The higher the rate/order, the faster the convergence.

The sequence you provide converges via the first limit to $1$ (work it out!), so it has neither a *rate of convergence* nor an *order of convergence*.